# Comparing multiple values at once using &&

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, operators, logic

I have this code:

```
if ((total == (total1 && total2 && total3)))
     {
        [scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake (0,0)];
     }
```

here is what it's something like on button action:

```
if (sender.tag == 1)
    {
        total1 = 10;
    }

if (sender.tag == 2)
    {
        total2 = 20;
    }

if (sender.tag == 3)
    {
        total3 = 30;
    }
```

I am trying to go back to the start page of the scroll view if the user clicked the three correct buttons (similar to a password key).

Does the logical operator `&&` work well in Objective-C, and did I use it right?

Comment: You need to explain what values total, total1, total2 and total3 may have.

Comment: there you go. hope it helps to find answer to my question.

Comment: How many buttons do you have? What happens when the user presses these buttons but others too? What happens when the user presses one of these buttons two or more times?

Comment: i have 30 buttons, When the user got the correct combination the value of total will set back to zero and will go back to the start page. The other buttons has their own values too, when they pressed the wrong combination it'll say try again.

Comment: I edited my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((total == (total1 && total2 && total3)))
```

You cannot do that. You have to explicitly compare each separately.

```
if ((total == total1) && (total == total2) && (total == total3)))
```

But that leaves the question of how `total` can be equal to all the three simultaneously though.

Comment: i tried it but it executes the codes when i started to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
if ((total == (total1 && total2 && total3)))
{
   [scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake (0,0)];
}
```

When the if expression is evaluated, `(total1 && total2 && total3)` is evaluated first. And that can be either `YES` or `NO` (true or false if you prefer), or (0 or 1).

So your code is equivalent to the following:

```
BOOL allVariablesAreNotZero = total1 && total2 && total3;
if (total == allVariablesAreNotZero)
{
   [scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake (0,0)];
}
```

**Edit** after the question was better explained

Make your buttons perform the following action when pressed:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttonsCombination = buttonsCombination | (1 << button.tag);
}
```

Where `buttonsCombination` is an NSUInteger. Then use the following test to see if the buttons that were pressed are the correct ones (I am doing this with three buttons, but you guess the idea)

```
NSUInteger correctCombination = (1 << button1) | (1 << button2) | (1 << button3)
if (buttonsCombination == correctCombination) {
// The combination is correct
} else {
    // The combination is incorrect
}
buttonsCombination = 0;
```

Finally, note that this works because there are enough bits in a NSUInteger for 30 buttons.
Here I used [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) `|` and `<<`.

Comment: can i ask a dumb question? what's button1, button2 and button3?? sorry, i'm such a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

What your current code is essentially saying is "if `total` is 'true' and `total1`, `total2`, and `total3` are also all nonzero or if `total` is zero and `total1`, `total2`, and `total3` are also all zero, then do something".

The `&&` you have there is doing a logical/boolean comparison.  It treats its arguments as being either `true` or `false`, and returns `true` if both arguments evaluate to `true` and `false` in any other case.  The `==` compares the value of `total` with the `true` or `false` value that was obtained from your `&&` expressions.  That is probably not what you want here.

It seems like probably what you want to be saying is "if `total` is equal to the sum of `total1`, `total2`, and `total3`, then do something".  Assuming this is the case, you would do:

```
if (total == (total1 + total2 + total3)) {
    [scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake (0,0)];
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it executes the codes when i started to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to determine what you mean by your comment on two other answers "i tried it but it executes the codes when i started to run the app" maybe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
/* all in your button handler */
switch(sender.tag)
{
   case 1:
      total1 = 10;
      break;
   case 2:
      total2 = 20;
      break;
   case 3:
      total3 = 30;
      break;
   default:
      break; // other buttons are ignored
}
// check it latest click means the total is now correct
if((total1 + total2 + total3) == total)
{
   [scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake (0,0)];
}
```

So you update any totalX's effected by the button click and then check the condition to reset the scrolling.